# App crashes with exception before Activity.onCreate() Java android

Tags: java, android, exception

I get this weird exception:

```
libcore.io.ErrnoException: access failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

All I did was that I modified `res/layout/main_activity.xml`

But when I roll back to the previous situation, I get same exception.  I know this looks like the problem is elsewhere, but I just can't figure where.
Any hints, please ?

Here is part of the back trace in the relevant thread:
This is an export of back trace of the main thread. Problem is in the top most line.

```
<1> main@830012765280, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access(ForwardingOs.java:38)
      at java.io.File.doAccess(File.java:283)
      at java.io.File.exists(File.java:363)
      at dalvik.system.DexPathList.splitAndAdd(DexPathList.java:168)
      at dalvik.system.DexPathList.splitPaths(DexPathList.java:149)
      at dalvik.system.DexPathList.splitLibraryPath(DexPathList.java:130)
      at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:98)
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:52)
      at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:65)
      at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:57)
      at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:302)
      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:474)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityTh3938)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)read.java:
```

....

Comment: did you try access any file from SDCard or internal storage?

Comment: post the code ,so that we may find the bug !

Comment: Did you changed some file names ?

Comment: @ Hamid: Yap, I tried read from internal storage. pdf file opens fine..
..
@ Vamsi: There is not much to paste. Only XML, which is compiled ok. The problem is before pc gets to my code. I could paste the back trace though.
..
@Mert: Nop, filenames are same AFAIK... Let me recheck.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project so everything gets built anew? Sometimes the R classes are generated the wrong way which leads to all kinds of weird errors.

Comment: @ Mert:  I have just rechecked the previous version. Same filenames - only that I have moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ, which has added some IDE files. However, I had this problem already with eclipse. Funny thing is, that the installed app would run in my device, but it crashed with every single attempt to debug (special features) :-o

Comment: @ Ridcully: Yap - I tried to rebuild everything from scratch with both IntelliJ and Eclispe, before I posted this thread.

Comment: You need to post the full error log, not this partial version

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, you save your time and sanity by rolling back to previous version and start over.
Even better - use another IDE than Eclipse.
That's exactly what I did and it helped in full sence.